# Travel options from Latvia or Lithuania to Saint Petersburg or Kaliningrad

Tags: trains, russia, ferries, lithuania, latvia

Is it possible to travel from Latvia or Lithuania to Saint Petersburg or Kaliningrad by ferry or train?

We will be traveling to these countries this summer. My wife wants to visit her mother.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What has your own research on this itinerary revealed?

Comment: I think bus is possible.

Comment: The EU is now planning the **11th** sanctions package against Russia. Between now and this summer, the rules might change yet again.

Comment: At least no trains, it appears. https://www.seat61.com/trains-and-routes/helsinki-to-st-petersburg-by-train.htm

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your wife status and citizenship, it is possible to board the train at the border stations in Lithuania: Kybartai, Kena.

But it might be easier and more convenient to take one of available buses.
Or even cross the border on foot.